# Powershell: How to extract part a file name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, filenames, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a file that follows this naming convention: `project.customer.version-number.zip`

So for example i might have a file called: `project.customer.1.1.889.zip`

The "version-number" will change.

"project" and "customer" will stay the same. The zip file extension will always be the same.

I long way to get it I have found is to use multiple Split paths and then concatenate together to get the full version number. So i would have:

```
$1 = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[2];
$2 = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[3];
$3 = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[4];
$version = $1 + "." + $2 "." + $3
```

Is there a quicker / better way to extract just the version number (i.e. the 1.1.889) if i don't know what it will be every time with powershell?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i've tried spilt-path. So 'i've tried 'Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[0]' - but there are "." within the version number and throughout the file name so don't think it is the best option / how i would get it to work.

Comment: So, `$project,$customer,$version = ((Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf) -replace '\.zip$').Split(".",3)` is what you need I think.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician this works and is perfect, much cleaner! thank you!

Comment: If the file path/name doesn’t ever have a number you could do `$filepath -replace ‘^.+(?=\d)|\.zip’` to get just the version

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people don't realize you can specify how many times to split a thing, and it comes in handy more often than you'd think.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Could you please add this as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of item that split returns. In this case you just want to split it into Project, Customer, and Version. First we'll reduce it to just the file name with `Split-Path -leaf`, then we remove the file extension with `-replace`, and then we'll split the remaining file base name 3 times.

```
$project,$customer,$version = ((Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf) -replace '\.zip$').Split(".",3)
```